# Discord.py how to disable commands with discord.ext.commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to disable an command, but i dont know how it works

this is the command i want to disable

```
@client.command(description="Sends an random gif", aliases=['gifje', 'GIF', 'Gif'], brief="Sends an random gif (NO NSFW)")
discord.ext.commands.Command(name="gif", cls=None, enabled=False)
#@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
async def gif(ctx):
    links = ["https://gph.is/1N1s5AR",
             "https://gph.is/2nmNhuw",
             "https://gph.is/g/ajWp6mj",
             "https://gph.is/g/apbGw0O",
             "https://gph.is/g/Z5YMP9Q",
             "https://gph.is/g/aQOvqQ5",
             "https://gph.is/g/ajW9Nx8",
             "https://gph.is/2CF8W7r",
             "http://gph.is/17GL4ua",
             "https://gph.is/12kQg0y"]
    await ctx.send(random.choice(links))
```

i believe i have to do it with discord.ext.commands but i dont know how (i dont want to use cogs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.remove_command(name)`

You can create a command that runs this command and it will be unavailable until added back or the bot is restarted.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.remove_command

Comment: Well iknow the remove command, but i want it disabled so i can easy make an disabledcommand error.

Comment: You can update a command's attributes by calling `update` on the command. That way you can set the `enabled` attribute to False and then raise your error.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=disable#discord.ext.commands.Command.update

Answer (score 1):

**`.update(enabled=False)`**

You can get the [`Command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command) object by going through [`Bot.commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.commands) to find the command you're looking for. Once you've found the right command object, you can use its [`update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.update) method to edit the [`enabled`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.enabled) attribute.

Setting this attribute to `False` will result in a [`DisabledCommand`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.DisabledCommand) error being raised upon calling the command, which you can handle as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```py
    @commands.command(name="toggle", description="Enable or disable a command!")
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def toggle(self, ctx, *, command):
        command = self.client.get_command(command)

        if command is None:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="ERROR", description="I can't find a command with that name!", color=0xff0000)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        elif ctx.command == command:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="ERROR", description="You cannot disable this command.", color=0xff0000)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        else:
            command.enabled = not command.enabled
            ternary = "enabled" if command.enabled else "disabled"
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Toggle", description=f"I have {ternary} {command.qualified_name} for you!", color=0xff00c8)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This is the easiest way I use to disable/enable commands